# Confirm delete with php var

Tags: javascript, php

A sample of my code :

```
    <form action="test.php" method="GET">

        <input type="text" name="Delete_This" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['Delete_This'])) echo $_GET['Delete_This']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="Deleting" value="Delete this">

        <?php
            // If the deleting button is pressed
            if (isset($_GET['Deleting']))
            {

                $DeleteThis = $_GET['Delete_This'];

               ?> 
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo $DeleteThis ?> ?'))
                        alert('<?php echo $DeleteThis ?> deleted');
                         <?php
                           $sql_delete="DELETE FROM table WHERE Name like '".$DeleteThis ."'";
                           mysqli_query($db,$sql_delete);
                        ?>
                   else
                    alert('Not deleted');


                </script>               
        <?php } ?>
    </form>
```

The confirm box opens proprely. My problem is that wether i click on **OK** or **Cancel**, `$sql_delet` is executed.
I know I should use Javascript on the top `<head>` of my document but if i do that I can't execute the Delete query and I must warn the user what he's going to delete. `{$DeleteThis}` works fine. I also used the `onclick` function on the `input` but I can't use `{$DeleteThis}`.

To synthesize : I want, if the `confirm` box is canceled, the query not to be executed and I must use php variable in the `confirm` and `alert`.

Comment: PHP is dead by the time your confirm box loads. Wrong approach. Use that confirmation box before the form is submitted to PHP code

Comment: I didn't know it worked like that. What i want to do isn't possible then ? How can I execute a `Delete` query ONLY if the the confirm is OK

Comment: @Epodax kinda, a better way to put it is that PHP runs on the web server and generates what the browser sees. JS runs on the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read up on the difference between server-side and client-side languages.

Everything you put in php code is executed before the html and javascript code is even sent to the user's browser.

In contrast, everything you put in javascript code can no longer affect the php code.

So what happens in your code is that php first checks whether there is a `$_GET['Deleting']` variable. If there is one, it finds some html and javascript, and remembers that it should output that to the browser later. It then executes the delete query. And once it's done, it sends the following javascript (plus any surrounding html) to the browser:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your-deletion-value ? \nHey'))
        alert('your-deletion-value deleted');

   else
    alert('Not deleted');


</script>
```

So hopefully, you see the disconnection between the two.

Comment: Yes, I now understand how it works. So I can't `DELETE` query only if the `CONFIRM` box is clicked on OK ? I just want the user to check if he made a mistake

Comment: Well, you can make the confirmation box, and then only send the form to the deletion script if the user pressed okay. That would work fine. You just add an `onclick` to the submit button - like in Elyor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could put confirmation in

```
if (isset($_GET['Deleting']))
        {

            $DeleteThis = $_GET['Delete_This'];
            if(!isset($_GET['ConfirmDelete'])//if confirmation has not been initiated yet
            {
           ?> 

            <script type='text/javascript'>
            function deleteOrNot(formEle)
            {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo $DeleteThis ?> ?'))
                    window.location += '&ConfirmDelete=yes';//casue a postback with ConfirmDelete attribute in $_GET

               else
                alert('Not deleted');
            </script>               
    <?php }
          else if($_GET['ConfirmDelete'] == 'yes')
             {
                 $sql_delete="DELETE FROM table WHERE Name like '".$DeleteThis ."'";
                 mysqli_query($db,$sql_delete);
             }
 } ?>
```

Or you could use a a checkbox in your form with a required attribute then set the submit button to set the value of the checkbox before submitting with an onclick.

```
<input type="checkbox" name='ConfirmDelete' 
    required <?php if(isset($_GET['ConfirmDelete']))  
        echo 'checked=' . $_GET['ConfirmDelete']; ?> >
<input type="submit" name="Deleting" onclick=
      'this.form.ConfirmDelete.checked = deleteOrNot(this.form)' value="Delete this">
```

and change your script like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function deleteOrNot(formEle)
    {
        if(typeof formEle == 'undefined')
        {
            formEle = forms[0];
        }
        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete' + formEle.Delete_This.value + ' ? \nHey');
        if (result)
            alert(formEle.Delete_This.value + ' will be deleted');
        else
            alert('Not deleted');
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

> **Note:** I added the form as an argument to the deleteOrNot function and use that to get the value of the text box. The required on the checkbox will prevent form submission if it is not checked

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
```

Comment: I know that `onclick` works. But I want the user to see what he's going to delete. I don't want the confirm to be 'You want to delete this', I want 'You want to delete {Name}'

Comment: This is my post. I don't criticize your post though